# "core-header-panel" element of Polymer is not showing text inside content Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I have used "core-header-panel" element of Polymer in my application, However Not sure why contents inside div is not visible.

Complete code at - http://jsfiddle.net/ilovenagpur/5rm4eznm/1/

please suggest if i am missing something here.

Code Snippet :

```
<body fullbleed unresolved vertical layout> 
    <core-header-panel > 
            <core-toolbar class="medium-tall">  
                <div flex>I am Heading</div> 
                <core-icon-button icon="search"></core-icon-button>

                <paper-tabs class="bottom fit" selected="0">
                    <paper-tab>This Week</paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab>Next Week</paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab>History</paper-tab>
                </paper-tabs> 
            </core-toolbar> 
        <div class="content">   
             THIS <br />
          COMPONENT <br />
          IS NOT <br />
          VISIBLE <br />
            THIS <br />
          COMPONENT <br />
          IS NOT <br />
          VISIBLE <br />
            THIS <br />
          COMPONENT <br />
          IS NOT <br />
          VISIBLE <br />
            THIS <br />
          COMPONENT <br />
          IS NOT <br />
          VISIBLE <br />

            <footer layout vertical center>
                <div  >I am footer</div>  
            </footer> 
        </div>
    </core-header-panel>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix issue. and achieved desired output without `core-header-panel` , Here is working code.

http://jsfiddle.net/ocw5x2aL/8/

Thanks namiheike for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Via the secend video on [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/layout-elements.html) page:

> Both `core-header-panel` itself and the parent (`body` in your code), need an explicit height set.

So I guess you may wanna try `<core-header-panel flex>`

---

update:

I tried your code, the problem is in your stylesheet.

Those "invisible" text are actually "under" the core-toolbar.

Comment: Hi namiheike, even if i add many text with line breaks it is not working.

Comment: what I have done is: 1. make core-header-panel `flex`; 2. remove the `tab` and clear the styles. then using the inspector I found the text under the toolbar.

Comment: And if i simply remove `core-header-panel` then it works however Ink effect on `paper-tab` doesn't work.